How more is regular KF used inside commercial application compared to UKF?
I have used both KF and UKF. Both works great. UKF is more unstable and very sensitive to corrupted data, compared to KF.
So my question is: How more is regular KF used inside commercial application compared to UKF?
What If have seen are:

KF is more used in education
KF is more common compared to UKF
UKF is more for research
KF is used in practice e.g robotics


Well, it’s probably impossible to give an exact answer because I don’t know all commerical applications where a KF is used. But, the general rule I was told is that the UKF is specifically for highly nonlinear predict and update functions where the linearization in the EKF breaks down. So, if I had to guess, the KF/EKF are probably used more in practice.

That would be easier to read you tell us what you mean by KF and UKF. Not everyone uses the same acronyms.

@Hilmar "Kalman Filter" and "Unscented KF" (see tags); I'd agree, however, the context of this question is a bit strange. (and the purpose of the question is also a bit confusing: What does it matter what is used more commonly? Industry also uses a lot more metal screws than it uses wind turbines, but if you want to make energy out of wind, a wind turbine is more useful)

My bad. I didn't see the tags
